# fatal: cherry-pick failed >>> error: commit [...] is a merge but no -m option was given

Tags: git, gitlab, git-commit, git-cherry-pick

При попытки выполнить cherry-pick своего коммита, получаю ошибку

```
$ git cherry-pick 648df187f7d7269c4ff83bb0640abe443a0ac3ce
error: commit 648df187f7d7269c4ff83bb0640abe443a0ac3ce is a merge but no -m option was given.
fatal: cherry-pick failed
```

здесь есть объяснение почему https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229301/git-cherry-pick-says-38c74d-is-a-merge-but-no-m-option-was-given

но не могу понять как мне сформировать команду?
Так что ли, или как?

```
$ git cherry-pick 648df187f7d7269c4ff83bb0640abe443a0ac3ce -m 1 63cbb1b
```

Также не могу понять какой из этих родительских коммитоd №1 а какой №2, но то что у него ID c9b859f9 в этом я 100% уверен.

Подскажите кто сталкивался, плз. боюсь если не правильно сделаю потом вообще не разгребусь с последствиями...

[image: два родительских коммита]

Comment: `git cherry-pick -m 1 648df187f7d7269c4ff83bb0640abe443a0ac3ce`